# Why nodejs fs.statSync doesn't work as expected

Tags: node.js

I just want to test if a path is a file (it exists that I am sure - on Windows)

```
  function HttpHandler(Request, Response) {

      const fs = require('fs');

          Response.writeHead(200, {
              'Content-Type': 'text/html'
          }); 

          Response.write('c://test/test.html' + '</br>');

          if (fs.statSync('c://test/test.html').isFile()) {

          }

          Response.end();

  }
```

It works ONLY ON FIRST request. But if I reload, I get this error:

> binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path), statValues);
>
> ```
>       ^
> ```
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
>   'C:\test\test\favicon.ico'

Comment: Might I ask where does the `file` variable coming from?

Comment: @FelixFong sorry it's just 'c://test/test.html' . I also updated the error

Comment: Maybe you can try setting up a router to handle the `favicon.ico`?

Comment: @FelixFong I don't need favicon I just want to browse the file.

Comment: All web browsers will request a favicon and possibly a robots.txt